# How to get programatically 'display_options' for a specific page in Views

Tags: views, 8

I am a bit confused on how I should code this...
I have a view based on a custom content entity with 4 displays: default (hidden), Page (page_1), Export Entité (rest_export_1) and Export pour Maps (rest_export_2).

[image]

Devel shows this for this view:
[image]

I'd like to get the value of the path for 'rest_export_1' to use it in `$name`.
My code:

```
function association_exportCSV($view, $page)
{
  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view);
  $name = ???
  $page = $view->preview($page);
  file_unmanaged_save_data($page , 'private://' . $name . '.csv', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

}
```

What should I do next? How to get $name from 'path'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
function association_exportCSV($view, $page) {
  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view);
  // $display_id in this case is  'rest_export_1
  $view->setDisplay($page);
  $path = $view->getPath();
  file_unmanaged_save_data($page, 'private://' . $path . '.csv', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```

Comment: Finally, I came to the same result with   
`$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view);
 $display = $view->storage->getDisplay($page);
 $path = $display['display_options']['path'];`  
but in both cases, I get this message: `Notice : Array to string conversion dans file_unmanaged_save_data()`.
Any idea?

Comment: $page passed to `file_unmanaged_save_data`  should be a string, if you want to save result of view should do something like `file_unmanaged_save_data( $data, 'private://' . $path . '.csv', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);` `$data` should be string of view result .

Comment: `$data = $view->preview($page)['#markup'];`does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
function association_exportCSV($view, $page)
{

  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view);

//Solution 1
  $display = $view->storage->getDisplay($page);
  $path = $display['display_options']['path'];

//Solution 2
  $view->setDisplay($page);
  $path = $view->getPath();

  $data = $view->preview($page)['#markup'];
  file_unmanaged_save_data($data , 'private://' . $path, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

}
```